# Code to insert Rows to a Table in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add rows to my table using the code below. I keep getting an error. I doesn’t like the colons and if I take them out (although I need them in there) it then doesn’t like the 356’s. If I remove them it then doesn’t like something else.

I am using phpMyAdmin and thought I was using MySQL but the error messages mention MariaDB.

BTW, the book I am working through shows `‘  ‘` around the values to be inserted but I have found I can only insert values surrounded by `“   “`.
What do I need to change to get this working in phpMyAdmin?

```
INSERT INTO colours (ID, ColourCode)
VALUES
(“356-30-127”, “356-30-127 : Red”),
(“356-30-128”, “356-30-128 : White”);
```

Comment: can you please share two column data type

Comment: Write your error please, and write your table structure please... I think the problem is because the length of the table attribute.

Comment: Hi, the datatype for both columns is varchar(150)

Comment: When I try to run the code it shows Unexpected character for both the colons. It returns the error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ': Red’),
(‘356-30-128’, ‘356-30-128 : White’)' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

For data insertion you have to use " or ' in string type
check below query it works

```
 create table colours (ID varchar(200),ColourCode varchar(200));
    INSERT INTO colours (ID, ColourCode) 
    VALUES ('356-30-127', '356-30-127 : Red'), 
    ('356-30-128', '356-30-128 : White');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a14a8/1

Comment: I am pasting the code in from Notepad. I have found that if I delete all the ' (tildes) in the phpMyAdmin SQL window and re-type them, the code works. Not sure why?

Comment: @DavidBall i said in my answer that you typed wrong apostrophe for insert statement you have type ' or " for my sql and i show you that my answered please accept my answer if it helps